# How to re"build" an already-working open source mobile app in IntelliJ?

Tags: android, mobile, intellij-idea

I want to write a few unit tests in IntelliJ to test out an app I have found on F-Droid called AAT. I want to use the source code available on F-Droid to build the application in IntelliJ/run it on an emulator/test the application using a few unit tests that I've written in IntelliJ.

However, I'm confused about how I would upload the source code for an app in IntelliJ. How would I use the source code for an app to "build" it in IntelliJ? Also, how would I have to structure my project files to be able to run my unit tests on the application once its been built?

Please let me know if I'm not being clear enough, thank you.

Comment: You'd typically use Android Studio (a mod of intellij from Google) to do Android work.  And I would expect the source repository to have it in the correct structure.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this by creating a new project from version control (Github) and specifying the url for the project repository on Github!